# How to set download directory in DownloadManager?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I am using DownloadManager but it puts the download somewhere I don't know. I want to download the file in a specific folder like "mp3" in sdcard.

Here is the code I am using :

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        if(url.endsWith(".mp3") || !url.startsWith("http://xnm")) {
            String servicestring = Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE;
            DownloadManager downloadmanager;
            downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(servicestring);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new Request(uri);
            Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);

            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
         }
         else {
             mWebView.loadUrl(url);
             setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
         }

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url){
        super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
     }

}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I got it working after searching a lot and here it is the code to add in existing.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/any");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download/Global Mp3", nameOfFile);
```

And we need this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thats it !!! Maybe it will help someone else

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mp3")
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

to set the download path

Comment: fileuri is like "/mp3" or what? Sorry but i am new to android development

Comment: it giver error on "setDestinationUri" >> The method setDestinationUri(Uri) in the type DownloadManager.Request is not applicable for the arguments (URI)

Comment: Didn't make the difference... The file is still not downloading in mp3 folder!! Can u please post a full code for this issue.

Comment: Is there any permission needed to write in sdcard?

Comment: yes , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
```